# Flutter IconButton with original image color

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a typical Google login button in flutter and I would like to use the following image as the icon for my IconButton.
[image]

```
Ink(
   decoration: ShapeDecoration(
   color: theme.onPrimaryBackground,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
   ),
   child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () async {},
      iconSize:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
      icon: const ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/google.png'),
        )
      ), 
   ),
```

The problem here is that the original image multi-color pattern is overridden if you use IconButton.
Is using an Image inside an InkWell the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Don't use imageIcon it is quite difficult (kind of not possible) , rather simple use Image.asset("imagePath") and in there you can specify height and with.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. it may help

```dart
     GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {

                        //todo your logic

                  },
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      height: 50,
                      width: 235,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 35,
                            width: 30,
                            child: Image(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/google.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Google",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
```